# Filtering warnings in Visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, stylecop

I opened up a huge Solution in VS2008. I has about a little over a thousand style cop warnings. I don't have resharper or any other commercial visual studio add-ins. Is there any way I can filter the warnings, so I can just look at the items pertaining to one file (the current file)? I could sort by filename and scroll to the section for the current file but that isn't very convenient.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't.

What I've used when having many many many warnings is to change the code analysis settings for the project to show error on one  type. That would devide the number of errors you have with the number of code analysis types.